# How would you score a hidden ball trick?

Tags: baseball

If the defense runs a hidden ball trick on a base runner and gets him out, how would it be officially scored?  How about a scenario:

The defense meets on the mound where the second baseman is given the ball by the pitcher.  A runner on second is tagged out while wondering off the base by the second baseman.  Is this scored 4U?  Is it a caught stealing, a pick off, etc?

Comment: Not quite the same, but this is a cool play. [Link](http://tampabay.rays.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20130810&content_id=56561040&c_id=tb)

Comment: holy crap that video was frustrating. 2:47 for those who are impatient like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The putout would be an unassisted putout by the player who tagged the runner.

The fact that someone handed it to him earlier makes no difference.

Comment: I guess the question is why the pitcher is not credited with an assist.  If P throws to 2B (e.g. for a pickoff) and 2B applies the tag, P gets an assist, correct?  The same happens even if there is a rundown and several seconds elapse before the tag, so it doesn't seem to be about timing.  Is the issue that P handed the ball to 2B rather than making a throw?